# Trying to implement a method from my Model part of my MVC to the View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, model-view-controller

It does not seem to be working as expected. I have a mini quiz that I have created on iOS and in this quiz, I'm attempting to implement a method that returns the incorrect (missed) questions from my Model in the form of an array to my View Controller.

This is the method from the Model:

```
func incorrectItems() -> [String] {
        var theAnswer:String
        var theQuestion:String
        var inCorrectAnswers = [String]()

        for (var j = 0; j < myAnswers.count; j++) {
            theQuestion = myQuestions[j]
            theAnswer = myAnswers[j]
            if (theAnswer != myAnswers[j]) {
                inCorrectAnswers.append(myQuestions[j])
            }
        }
        return inCorrectAnswers
    }
```

Within my View Controller, I am trying to implement this code to appear in a text View:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(txtAnswerField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        model.recordAnswer(txtAnswerField.text!) //Have instance of model record answer from text field
        numCorrect = model.numOfCorrectAnswers //number of correct answers
        numWrong = model.numOfIncorrectAnswers //number of incorrect answers
        txtViewQuestionStatus.text = "\(model.incorrectItems())\n" //Have text view fill up with incorrect answers
        model.theQuestion++
        if model.hasMoreQuestions == true {
            model.theQuestion++
            updateQuestionAndAnswer()
        }
        txtAnswerField.text = ""
        txtAnswerField.resignFirstResponder() //hide keyboard
        return true
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You say "It does not seem to be working as expected." but never explain how. What did you expect to see, what did you see instead, what do you think the difference means and where do you need help?

Comment: Hello Jonah I expect to see my textView (txtViewQuestionStatus) fill up with the array of incorrect Answers from the inCorrectItems() method from my model. However, I'm not seeing anything returned in my TextView. Thanks!

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that my code is returning an empty array of incorrect Answers instead of having an array of Answers that were answered incorrectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was able to work out the proper code needed for another method I implemented earlier. The method involved misplaced code I left in another method recordAnswer(String). I went ahead and did a conditional statement and had the inCorrectItems method return all the answers that were not answered correctly.

Thank you everyone.